# How do I properly SELECT WHERE Effective_Date >= 'Given_Date' in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this select statement that returns the results I'm looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM Database.dbo.Table
WHERE Effective_Date >= '04/01/2014'
AND Chain = 'MCD'
```

I'm looking to turn this into a stored procedure with the following variables, @EffectiveDate and @Chain so that I can simply replace the date and chain to get different results. Here is the stored procedure I've made that doesn't work correctly:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Database.dbo.StoredProc
    @Chain VARCHAR(255),
    @EffectiveDate VARCHAR(255)
AS
     SELECT *
     FROM Database.dbo.Table
     WHERE Effective_Date >= '+@EffectiveDate+'
     AND Chain = '+@Chain+'
GO
```

I'd like to execute this stored procedure like this:

```
EXEC Database.dbo.StoredProc
@PharmacyChain = N'MCD',
@EffectiveDate = N'04/01/2014'
;
GO
```

In this example, Table.Effective_Date is in datetime format. When I run the SELECT statement w/o the stored proc, the date comparison works fine to only select records with effective date after '04/01/2014'. However, when it's run using the variables int he stored proc, it doesn't convert the date correctly to compare. I've tried changing the EffectiveDate variable to datetime format, but still had no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Parameters should match the column datatype

```
 @Chain VARCHAR(255) -- what is Chain?
 @EffectiveDate datetime -- or date etc
```

And simply do this

```
 SELECT *
 FROM dbo.Table
 WHERE Effective_Date >= @EffectiveDate 
 AND Chain = @Chain;
```

You don't need 3 part object names either